# Is there a way to connect a water tap to this Y hose splitter?

Tags: hose, spigot

I have this Y splitter so I can connect two hoses
Is there a way to connect (quick connect if possible) a spigot to they Y ?
I would like to add it where the pressure meter was connected

the valve you can guess under the pipe is a quarter turn ball valve which I think it gives me full pressure (please correct me if I am wrong saying full pressure) but I can't control the water volume and soak a sponge or put water in a bucker without soaking the patio or myself :-)

The pipe that comes out of the wall is 1/2" copper
[image]

Update: it seems that for full pressure I need a **full port ball valve spigot**

Comment: That pressure seems to be on the high side for long life of pipes/fittings.  Would like to see it dropped by about 30 pounds.

Comment: It has been so for 8 years and I think the system has been like that for years before we bought the house. As a mater of fact due to the fact that the basement has a kitchen and a bathroom as well there is not enough pressure to keep the upstairs and the downstairs taps running properly at the same time. I am considering a pressure tank added to the system. The city pipe is 3/4" the house is entirely built with 1/2"

Comment: quarter turn ball valve can be easily turned only part way ... turn the black lever on the Y adapter part way ... that will limit the flow ... don't forget that the pressure gauge will show full pressure even if there is only a pinhole for the water to flow through

Comment: the gauge is not permanently there I took the picture when I was trying to design my irrigation system

Comment: Full _pressure_ is achieved with minimal flow, e.g. a pinhole. Full _flow_ (or volume) is achieved when you have no constrictions, e.g. valve openings smaller than the pipe diameter, and and no bends. Trivia: High pressure hoses for SCUBA generally handle 3000PSI through a tiny orifice since it is used only to monitor the tank pressure. A failed hose will drain an 80 cubic foot tank in something like 20 minutes. The intermediate pressure hose, used for breathing, can empty a tank in closer to 2 minutes at about 150psi since it supplies more than the gas you could breathe at depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the plumbing upto the tube coming out of the house. Then you could install a "T" preferably brass. Then install two valves of the type you want. You could use the old one and 1 new one if you like. This will involve no soldering or anything like that. Just a few wrenches.  Be sure to back up the tubing fitting on the line coming from the house when you remove the old and install the new. Adding support for the new valves would be a good idea.

Comment: Valid solution but I simplified the problem by buying one of the adjustable flow nozzles from Orbit https://www.costco.com/orbit-2-pack-nozzles.product.100538780.html  (on sale in Canada for 14CAD)