# Do you fully open the shutoff valves for your sink supply lines?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The water tap is splashing water all over the place if we fully open the tap. The water flows well from the aerator-straight jets of liquid from each vent ..the splashing happens when it hits the sink, too much pressure I believe

The remedy for that was to adjust the pressure at shut off valve level but now I am having second thoughts, I am not sure if that was OK

I have two of these, my only issue right now is that they seem to be a little bit noisy in this half way open position
[image]

Update:
The aerator for the tap looks like this (I have another identical tap for the other bathroom
[image]
Whater meter
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the aerator on the faucet.  It can become clogged up a bit and water can spray, instead of flowing straight down.

Comment: Quarter turns valves aren’t great at pressure regulation. If you have to fiddle at this point, swap in multi turn valves.

Comment: Other than the noise could there be other problems with this?

Comment: It’s not a problem, technically, but a noisy faucet seems like a curse to me.

Comment: What is your water pressure? A simple gauge that screws onto an outside hose bib, would do the job, since the pressure would be equal everywhere, just make sure nobody is using water at the time you take the reading.   If you have a pressure reducing valve, it may need to be adjusted or repaired if pressure is too high.  It's hard to say what "standard" pressure is, but about 40-50 psi is typical. There's nothing wrong with leaving a cutoff valve partially open, but like others have said, you probably have a plugged aerator.

Comment: Here is the water pressure as measured a while ago https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248536/is-there-a-way-to-connect-a-water-tap-to-this-y-hose-splitter -see the picture in that post. That is static no tap opened in the house

Comment: The 'fix' for this is to either turn the tap down a bit or not point the water flow at the flat bottom of the sink; point it down an edge. Fast water splashes back… This is physics 101.

Comment: just updated the post with a picture of the aerator

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate: 1/4 valves that are noisy are often not meant to throw and doing so can wreck the seals over time

Answer (score 1):

*Water splashing everywhere* sounds like a missing aerator, or one with serious defects or missing parts. Try replacing that.

If the tap in question has no provision for an aerator, consider replacing the tap.

Comment: In hard water areas they can clog up with deposits.  Usually a simple soak with vinegar(or similar) will make them like new.

Comment: Maybe it is wrong wording on my side, the water flows well from the aerator-straight jets of liquid from each vent ..the splashing happens when it hits the sink

Comment: A properly working aerator provides a single stream of water with air bubbles in it, that is far less prone to splashing than un-aerated water. Most also incorporate a flow limiter. "Straight jets of liquid from each vent" does not sound like a working aerator.

Comment: this is the tap that I have https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/F-5821-3BN.pdf  On page 3,  16 is the rectifier that has the nozzles in it , the water comes out trough those. Not sure if that is what you call aerator

Comment: Doesn’t sound like this is the case, but sometimes people forget to remove the aerator for the initial flush of manufacturing crap, and the aerator ends up with crud that interrupts the stream.

Comment: That or just don't turn on the tap fully.

Comment: I want the water not to splash when the tap is fully open -really difficult to find the right  right level of opening the tap right now (or at least it is annoying)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, shut-off valves are not designed for regulating the water flow. They can do the job, but they may be noisy.

### Noise & Wear

The noise is a result of the friction generated inside the valve when it is not fully open. This friction may also create wear for which the valve is not designed, although I personally think this is not likely an issue. Remember that the valve is also an emergency shut off should the fixture (sink faucet) fail, and you want to be able to rely on that.

### Pressure & Eruption

Note that partially closing the valve does not reduce the static pressure to the spout (this is the pressure when water is not flowing). This means that the initial rush pressure when opening the tap can still lead to an "eruption" splash at the sink.

If this initial splash is acceptable to you, and the noise is tolerable, you have an interim solution. Tuning the right level of flow is difficult with a 1/4-turn valve, especially if the water pressure fluctuates due to a malfunctioning PRV or due to the pipe-layout throughout the house (e.g. washing machine filling drops pressure in kitchen)

### Check your PRV

In addition to checking the aerator in the spout, you should also check the water pressure throughout the house: it's possible you have a failing "PRV". An indication of failure is that the general pressure throughout the house fluctuates greatly between peak hours and off-hours in your neighbourhood, e.g. much higher pressure late at night than during the evening/morning. A further indication is that all your spouts seem to produce a high pressure flow.

The pressure can be measured using a pressure gauge attached to a garden bib. If your PRV is failing you should have it replaced as soon as possible, since high pressure increases the wear on valves, the risk of pipe/tubing rupture and damage to appliances.

Here's an example of what to look for:

[image]

Image: https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/1507s.jpg

Comment: I do not know if I have a PRV....ther e is a main shut off valve right after the water meter and from there the pipe goes u derground to the city supply pipe on the street.

Comment: are you able to add a picture of that? roughly where in the world are you located? I edited to add an example line-up.

Comment: I am in Toronto I added a picture of my water meter and shut off valve